# could configure jenkins slave in docker container from jenkins server in docker

Tags: docker, jenkins

I'm practicing docker in practice by manning.

The technical recipe is about configuring jenkins slave which is docker container.

Below is the Dockerfile for jenkins_slave

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN groupadd -g 1000 jenkins_slave
RUN useradd -d /home/jenkins_slave -s /bin/bash \
-m jenkins_slave -u 1000 -g jenkins_slave
RUN echo jenkins_slave:jpass | chpasswd
RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y openssh-server openjdk-8-jre wget iproute2 
RUN mkdir -p /var/run/sshd
CMD ip route | grep "default via" \
| awk '{print $3}' && /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

I built docker images using the command

```
docker build -t jenkins_slave .
```

Then I run the docker images as container using the command

```
$ docker run --name jenkins_slave -it -p 2222:22 jenkins_slave 
172.17.0.1
```

Then I run the jenkins server using the below docker command

```
$ docker run --name jenkins_server -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 dockerinpractice/jenkins:server
```

Below is the node configuration details -

[image: node configuration details]

Then I get the error message saying ***This agent is offline because Jenkins failed to launch the agent process on it***

[image: Slave node error]

Below is the error stack trace

```
[12/07/17 08:50:00] [SSH] Opening SSH connection to 172.17.0.1:2222.
/var/jenkins_home/.ssh/known_hosts [SSH] No Known Hosts file was found at 
/var/jenkins_home/.ssh/known_hosts. Please ensure one is created at this path and that Jenkins can read it.
Key exchange was not finished, connection is closed.
java.io.IOException: There was a problem while connecting to 172.17.0.1:2222
at com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:834)
at com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:703)
at com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:617)
at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.openConnection(SSHLauncher.java:1284)
at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$2.call(SSHLauncher.java:804)
at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$2.call(SSHLauncher.java:793)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Key exchange was not finished, connection is closed.
at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.KexManager.getOrWaitForConnectionInfo(KexManager.java:95)
at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager.getConnectionInfo(TransportManager.java:237)
at com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:786)
... 9 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The server hostkey was not accepted by the verifier callback
at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.KexManager.handleMessage(KexManager.java:548)
at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager.receiveLoop(TransportManager.java:790)
at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager$1.run(TransportManager.java:502)
... 1 more
```

I have a simple build configuration called test but the build is not running since the slave is offline.

[image: build configuration]

Any idea why the jenkins master is not identifying the slave server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the `Host Key verification strategy` to `Non verfiying Verification Strategy` in the node configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `Host Key verification strategy` method which checks the `known_hosts` file ( usually it's at `~/.ssh/known_hosts`). However the jenkins server is checking `/var/jenkins_home/.ssh/known_hosts`, which probably is empty now, in the docker container.

You can use `Manually provided key Verification Strategy` and paste the public key there or using other methods with the help of [this document](https://github.com/jenkinsci/ssh-slaves-plugin/blob/master/doc/CONFIGURE.md#host-key-verification-strategy).